# DOM path using $Component

Tags: visualforce, javascript

**This is now working.**  *The illustration and related code snippet is below alongwith the orignal question.*

Inspecting the element showed the DOM path does not need the outputPanel nor tab ID's. This path is used as a combination of page, form, pageBlock, pageBlockSection and value.

```
val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("{!$Component.page:form1:block1:LOB_CA:LOB_CA1:value1}").value);
```

Not getting these fields to add up or display if numbers not adding up to 100%. The inputfields are firing the jsctipt via onchange="checkNumbersEnviron();" Is there something wrong with the DOM path I am using on document.getElementById('{!$Component..... ?

[image]

```
<apex:page id="page" standardStylesheets="true" standardController="Account_Summary__c" readOnly="false" extensions="AccountSummaryController" showHeader="true" action="{!redirectCREPage}" >

<script type="text/javascript">
/*
Script checks and prints to output text if numbers add up to 100 or not. 
use of ParseInt will produce a NaN (not a number) condition should the user enter alpha numeric text. 
*/
function checkNumbersEnviron() {

    var val1 = 0;  // Percent Local Radius
    if(document.getElementById("{!$Component.page:form1:block1:LOB_CA:LOB_CA1:value1}") != null)
        val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("{!$Component.page:form1:block1:LOB_CA:LOB_CA1:value1}").value);
    if(isNaN(val1))
        val1 = 0;

    var val2 = 0; // Percent Intermediate Radius
    if(document.getElementById("{!$Component.page:form1:block1:LOB_CA:LOB_CA2:value2}") != null)
        val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("{!$Component.page:form1:block1:LOB_CA:LOB_CA2:value2}").value);
    if(isNaN(val2))
        val2 = 0;

    var val3 = 0; // Percent Intermediate Radius
    if(document.getElementById("{!$Component.page:form1:block1:LOB_CA:LOB_CA3:value3}") != null)
        val3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("{!$Component.page:form1:block1:LOB_CA:LOB_CA3:value3}").value);
    if(isNaN(val3))
        val3 = 0; 

    var tot = val1 + val2 + val3;   
    document.getElementById('{!$Component.page:form1:block1:LOB_CA:LOB_CA4:valueTotOpEnvironHidden}').value = tot; // use apex hidden input field to save value for validation rule.
    document.getElementById('{!$Component.page:form1:block1:LOB_CA:LOB_CA5:valueTotOpEnviron}').innerHTML = tot;   // writes to apex output field for UI benefit.  

    if (tot < 100 || tot > 100)  
    {
        document.getElementById('{!$Component.page:form1:block1:LOB_CA:LOB_CA6:answerEnviron}').innerHTML = 'Total percent operating environment not equal to 100.';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('{!$Component.page:form1:block1:LOB_CA:LOB_CA6:answerEnviron}').innerHTML = 'Total percent operating environment equal to 100.'; 
    }
}
</script>

<apex:form id="form1">
<!-- <apex:sectionHeader title="Comprehensive Risk Evaluation"  help="{!$Resource.Help_MaidenReUWGuidelines}"/> -->
<apex:pageBlock id="block1" dir="" >

<apex:outputPanel id="OutputTabPanel">
<apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="name2" id="theTabPanel" headerClass="tabPanel" tabClass="activeTab" inactiveTabClass="inactiveTab" > 
<apex:tab label="Comm Auto" name="tab3" id="tab3"  > 
<apex:outputPanel Style="width:100%;" id="InputTabPanel" layout="block"> 
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" id="LOB_CA" title="Commercial Auto" showHeader="false" >



<!-- ********** -->
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="col"  >
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Radius of Operations Breakdown (under construction)" StyleClass="col1" />
                    <apex:outputLabel value=""   /> 
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="col" >
                     <apex:outputLabel value=""   />  
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
<!-- ********** -->

                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="col" id="LOB_CA1" >
                    <apex:outputLabel value="local (0-50 Miles)"  StyleClass="col4"  />
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Account_Summary__c.CA_Operating_Environment_Rural__c}" StyleClass="col2" id="value1" html-value1="value1" onchange="checkNumbersEnviron();" /> 
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="col" >
                        <apex:outputLabel value=""  />  
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
<!-- ********* -->
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="col" id="LOB_CA2" >
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Intermediate (51-200 Miles)"  StyleClass="col4"  />
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Account_Summary__c.CA_Operating_Environment_Suburban__c}" StyleClass="col2" id="value2" onchange="checkNumbersEnviron();"  /> 
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="col" >
                        <apex:outputLabel value=""  />  
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
<!-- ********* -->
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="col" id="LOB_CA3" >
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Long Haul (> 200 Miles)"  StyleClass="col4"  />
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Account_Summary__c.CA_Operating_Environment_Urban__c}" StyleClass="col2" id="value3" onchange="checkNumbersEnviron();" /> 
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="col" >
                        <apex:outputLabel value=""  />  
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
<!-- ********* -->
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="col" id="LOB_CA4" >
                    <apex:outputLabel value=""  StyleClass="col4"  />
                    <apex:inputHidden value="{!Account_Summary__c.Total_Percent_Op_Environ__c}" id="valueTotOpEnvironHidden"  /> 
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="col" >
                        <apex:outputLabel value=""  />  
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>                    
<!-- ********* -->                    
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="col"  id="LOB_CA5" >
                    <apex:outputLabel value="TOTAL"  StyleClass="col4"  />
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Account_Summary__c.Total_Percent_Op_Environ__c}" id="valueTotOpEnviron" StyleClass="col2"   /> 
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="col" >
                        <apex:outputLabel value=""  />  
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>                    
<!-- ********* -->                     
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="col" id="LOB_CA6" >
                    <apex:outputText id="answerEnviron" value="" style="color:blue"   />
                    <apex:outputLabel value=""   /> 
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="col" >
                     <apex:outputLabel value=""   />  
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
<!-- ********** -->

</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:outputPanel> 
</apex:tab>    
</apex:tabPanel> 
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you have a problem. *Every* Visualforce parent (elements starting with `apex:`) between the root of the page and the element in question must have an ID, and must be referenced in $Component. In particular:

```
<apex:outputPanel Style="width:100%;" layout="block">
```

This is a parent of `LOB_CA`, and so needs an ID and needs to be referenced in your $Component merge fields. Alternatively, you can probably remove it or replace it with a simple `span` or `div` instead.

I personally prefer using a non-conflicting way of getting to my elements when possible. One way you can avoid the madness of dealing with these ID values could be to use an html pass-through attribute, then query for those instead:

```
<apex:inputHidden html-data-total-percent-op-environ="x" value="{!Account_Summary__c.Total_Percent_Op_Environ__c}" id="valueTotOpEnvironHidden"  />
```

Which would allow you to write something like this:

```
var totalPercentOpEnviron = document.querySelector("[data-total-percent-op-environ]").value;
```

This is compatible with all versions of browsers officially supported by Salesforce, and is a lot easier to manage when you have deeply nested elements as you do here.

Comment: first thing I tried adding id="InputTabPanel" to the outputPanel and referenced it in the JScript $Component. Still not getting the 'value' of the field. Shows as 0 thru the alerts.  Updated the source above.

Comment: Figured it out and updated the post for anyone else. Would be interested to see how you would use pass thru HTML attributes.

Answer (score 2):

You can `getElementsByTagName` to find the `input` and do the summation and as suggested by sfdcfox assign the `tot` in the hidden field.

```
    var tot;
    //identify the table 
    var table = document.getElementById('LOB_CA');
    //retrieve the row count
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    for(var i=0; i < rowCount; i++) {        
        var cells = table.rows[i].getElementsByTagName('input');
        alert('cells=' + cells); 
        if(cells.length>0){
            //print the inputField value
            tot = parseInt(cells[0].value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks. I want to stick with previous VisualForce pages where I've used the same approach.